# What mechanism to use with YouTube access in Android.

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, google-plus, youtube-data-api

I am trying to implement a simple mechanism to authenticate the user so that through my app he can interact with YouTube. But there are several points in which I am confused about, following is a list of the same:

1) What login mechanism to use? I have implemented G+ sign in however the docs here are very confusing:

a) https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication?hl=de
This link asks me to use an O - Auth 2 authentication, however

b)https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp?hl=de this link tells me a different story.

I simply want the user to gain access through her account and upload videos, why is this so much painful?

Comment: I followed first link. Hope you have read the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/) well. Anyway I didn't get that much trouble.

Comment: Yes the second link is quite confusing as it says not to use O -Auth and instead use G+ signin to do the same. Thanks a lot for your input :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the Authentication at [YouTube Direct Lite for Android](https://github.com/youtube/yt-direct-lite-android).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the same, on to it!